# First ODE problem solution different than WolframAlpha solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$-y'' +2y' - y = x$ , with conditions $y(0) = y(1) = 0$

I am supposed to find a solution for this problem, so I started with finding the result for the homogeneous equation, and i got
$y = c_{1}e^x + c_{2}xe^x$

using the conditions I get the answer for the complementary part to be zero.

So, for finding the particular solution, I used the method of undetermined coefficients and I got $-x - 2$.

This makes the solution 
$y(x) = yp + yc = -x - 2$

However, using WolframAlpha, I get [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-y%27%27%20%2B%202y%27%20-y%20%3Dx%2C%20y%280%29%20%3D%200%2C%20y%281%29%20%3D0) .. so, where did I go wrong?

Comment: The conditions $y(0)=y(1)=0$ should be checked on the complete (homogenous + particular) solution, here on $$y(x)=(c_1+c_2x)e^x-x-2.$$ Thus, for example, $c_1=2$...

Comment: Isn't the solution to a differential equation a sum of the particular integral (PI) and complementary function? Looks like you've only written the PI here.

Comment: @Did-spot on here.

Comment: @John , we were taught the general solution of a non-homogeneous system is the sum of the homogeneous system (complementary solution) and the particular solution, and this is what I was trying to implement here.

Comment: @Did why would i choose an arbitrary value for the constant, when i clearly have initial conditions? :/

Comment: @ 32px, Pls see my post below-and please read more about the subject from the link.

Comment: @ 32px, You're right-this is a non-homogeneous case.

Comment: Where do you read that I suggest to "choose an arbitrary value for the constant"?

Comment: @Did I am sorry, I misunderstood the answer, so I thought you chose c1 to be 2, but after solving it I realised what you meant! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Did has alluded to in his comment, you need to use the initial conditions to solve the following equation in order to get the full solution (which is a sum of the *particular integral* and the *complementary function*):

i.e. Solve the following equation (for $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$)

$y = (c_{1} + c_{2}x)e^x - x - 2$

using the boundary condition $y(0) = y(1) = 0$

See this [link](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=xBOPVc6FD6zj8wfOlqygAw&gws_rd=ssl#q=particular+integral+and+complementary+function) for more details.

Comment: alright, thank you so much, I was trying to solve each solution of the differential equation separately which may have caused the error.

Comment: @32px, you're most welcome.